# Does anyone recognize the characters written here? (Characters identified: 天倫樂敘)

Tags: meaning, characters, character-identification

Does anyone recognize the characters written here? I've tried to figure it out but still can't understand what is written there, since I've just recognized the rightmost character, 天. It's a carving in my grandfather's house.

[image]

---

### UPDATE

1. The 1st character: 敘 | 叙 (xù)
2. The 2nd character: 樂 | 乐 (lè)
3. The 3rd character: 倫 | 伦 (lún)
4. The 4th character: 天 (tiān)

I've tried to show it to my 老师, who comes from the Guangdong province, and she said that the characters are read from right to left (since it is the old way of writing on carvings), and she has guessing the meaning of that sentence is (if I remember correctly): **"All generations of this family will always be happy"**.

Comment: 2nd character (in simplified) is 乐

Comment: @StumpyJoePete: Hi, thanks for the clue! XD

Comment: I suspect this is read from right to left, and that the second character is 倫 (伦) as in 天伦. The only saying I know that begins with these three characters is 天倫樂事 (天伦乐事) but that last character doesn't look much like 事.

Comment: @B.D: It seems you are correct! =D , my teacher said that it must read read from right to left, and she also doesn't recognized the first character. She said that it is such a really old character..

Comment: Handwriting it on nciku (http://www.nciku.com/search/zh/) brings up 叙, but this is not a use I have seen before. Googling 天伦乐叙 in quotation marks brings up a fair amount of hits, so that's probably what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm quite sure it is `天伦乐叙`. Search for `天伦乐叙、乐叙天伦、天伦叙乐` on google or baidu, there are many results. Like [this](http://baike.baidu.com/view/4215901.htm).